# How can I get the Basic Estimable Functions for a design matrix in R?

Tags: r, anova, estimation, sas, lm

When using the GLM procedure in SAS for an overparametrized ANOVA model, it shows you the General Form of the Estimable Functions for the given model, i.e. the basis of the functions of the model parameters that can be uniquely estimated without regard to the restrictions used on the parameters. How can I get this same output in R?

Comment: For those readers unfamiliar with this feature of ```SAS```, can you show us an example of what it does?